# aws s3 CLI, unable to copy entire directory structure

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have the following directory structure

```
first/
      second/
             file.txt
```

If I do `aws s3 cp first s3://bucket-name --recursive` the file copied in s3 has the path `bucket-name/second/file.txt` not `bucket-name/first/second/file.txt`

Why it doesn't behave like the `cp` command on Linux and how can I achieve the later?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
aws s3 cp first s3://bucket-name/first/ --recursive
```

This mimics normal Linux behaviour, such as:

```
cp -R first third
```

Both will result in the contents of `first` being put into the target directory. Neither commands creates a `first` directory.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I tried on ubuntu 18.04 `cp -r first third` would make the `first` directory

Comment: Interesting! That doesn't match the behaviour on Amazon Linux or my Mac.